# How can I stop Kivy from auto-selecting items modulo n in a RecycleView?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, selection

**The situation:** The code below uses Kivy's RecycleView class to spawn a GUI showing a table of data. Each row of this table starts with a red "Ignore" button whose color the user is supposed to be able to toggle between red and green by clicking.

**The problem:** When I click on a row's "Ignore" button, it not only turns the clicked button green, but also turns many other buttons further down the list green as well! The unwanted selection happens cyclically, that is, it seems that every *n*-th button turns green.

Why does this happen? How can I get Kivy to stop doing this, and instead select *only* the button that was clicked?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior


Builder.load_string('''
<Row@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    data: [None, None, None, None]
    IgnoreButton:
        text: 'Ignored'  if self.selected else 'Ignore'
        background_normal: ''
        # color green if ignored, otherwise red
        background_color: [0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 1] if self.selected else [0.5, 0, 0.1, 1]
    Label:
        text: str(root.data[1])
    Label:
        text: str(root.data[2])
    Label:
        text: str(root.data[3])
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'Row'
    data: [{'data':[0, x, x+1, x+2]} for x in range(100)]
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        multiselect: True
''')

class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                  RecycleBoxLayout):
    ' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '

class IgnoreButton(Button, RecycleDataViewBehavior):
    # Add selection support to the Button.
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        # Add selection on touch down.
        if super().on_touch_down(touch):
            self.selected = not self.selected

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a Recycleview,  there are only as many widgets as you can see… they get recycled.  Therefore you can not rely on the widget to store the state.
In Row, I created an NumericProperty, idx, and create an index in the rvdata list.  This corresponds to the index of the ‘virtual widget’.
I created a list to store the state of the ToggleButton.

You were treating a Button, like a ToggleButton, so I replaced It with a ToggleButton.  You can add the color changes back.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView


Builder.load_string('''
<Row>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    data: [None, None, None, None]
    ToggleButton:
        text: 'Ignored'  if app.root.selected[root.idx] == 'normal' else 'Ignore'
        #background_normal: ''
        # color green if ignored, otherwise red
        #background_color: [0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 1] if app.root.selected[root.idx] == 'normal' else [0.5, 0, 0.1, 1]
        state: app.root.selected[root.idx]
        on_state: app.root.selected[root.idx] = self.state
    Label:
        text: str(root.data[1])
    Label:
        text: str(root.data[2])
    Label:
        text: str(root.data[3])
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'Row'
    data: [{'data':[0, x, x+1, x+2], 'idx': x} for x in range(100)]
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
''')


class Row(BoxLayout):
    idx = NumericProperty()


class RV(RecycleView):
    selected = ListProperty(['normal'] * 100)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```